# How to authenticate on heroku Elastic Cloud, Elastic Search 5.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, elasticsearch

I have added addon `elastic clould` on my `heroku` app for `elasticsearch 5.X`. When I tried to login `elasticsearch` server it's asking for `username` and `password`. I have no idea where can I get the default `username` and `password`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will find an navigation called `Shield` on `heroku` `elastic clould`, go there and you will see an `Reset` button, when you click on it, this will give an `password` for default user `elastic`.

Enable `Kibana` from `Configuration` and login with this credential. Go to `management` tab, here you can manage your `users`, add an new user.

Finally use your newly created users credentials to login to `elasticsearch` server.

Comment: Also note that in recent versions the pw reset in under "Security" now, not "Shield" and the uname and pw provided is good for regular Kibana login, not admin login.